# Context-sensitive help on selected word in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any way, in Sublime Text, to get help about the currently highlighted keyword? For example, I select the word "file_get_contents", I press F1, and the PHP help page, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php, opens in a browser.

Is it possible to do this? I doesn't seem to be built-in and I couldn't find any plugin.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGtAgsGWis4

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to add the comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have to say that for me this video is the first google search result for *sublime php manual plugin* :)

Comment: @SergioFC, yep my Google skills failed me :) I've searched all kind of combinations like "sublime contextual help" or "sublime selected word documentation" but Google assumes it means help about Sublime Text or how to select a word in Sublime. Perhaps the keyword was "manual" or "php".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **sublime plugin** called *[GotoDocumentation](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-goto-documentation)* that works for PHP and many other languages. You can also set the desired *key binding*. In [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGtAgsGWis4) there is a complete example of what you're looking for.